# How to create Work Item without Task in TFS 2013?

Tags: tfs, workflow

In TFS 2013, for every work item (product backlog item, bug etc.) a task has to be created. So every time a bug is created or a backlog item is added, at least one additional linked task needs to be created.

This makes it quite cumbersome to maintain the system. Is there a way to just create one work item that goes from the backlog to being developed to being tested without having to create additional tasks?

Maybe this could be done via a different process template? I’ve tried both scrum and agile build in templates from Microsoft.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. _Why_ do you have to create a linked task to every work item? This is certainly not the default behavior. Have you applied custom plugins?

Comment: Be more explicit: I see something bugs you, but it is not clear.

Comment: What I mean is that a work item needs to have at least one task associated with it. I.e. If I create a bug then the bug item cannot be assigned and put in an iteration without creating a corresponding task. Only that task can then be moved through the various phases i.e. In progress, done etc. How to make it so a task is not needed for this i.e. just creating the bug can be moved through various phases?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [new article on MSDN that addresses this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920163.aspx), at least for bugs.  It shows how to make bugs act as tasks in TFS.  You could theoretically expand it for any work item (although I'm not sure this is advisable).